# style for constraintLayout not detect by Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

i have AppCompatText in a ConstraintLayout like this:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/id2"
                style="@style/H1"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_32dp"
                android:text="@string/text1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id1" />
```

and style like this:

```
<style name="H1">
    <item name="android:textAlignment">viewEnd</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/common_black</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">16dp</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf">parent</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintStart_toStartOf">parent</item>
</style>
```

but android studio show me error message: 
this view is not constraint horizontally:at runtime it will jump to the left unless you add horizontal constraint

Have I done anything wrong?

ps 1: view show correct in runtime and in layout designer

ps 2: my environment is: android studio 3.5
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312, built on August 9, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

ps 3: after update android studio from 3.2.1 to 3.5 this happen

ps 4:i know if add `tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"` error disappears

Answer (score 0):

Adding constraints inside style does work sometimes but android studio don’t support this. At least not yet. Take the constraints out of style and keep it in your xml file only. It will work.